# function will be run each time a match is found within the string

Tags: javascript, replace, match

I have a string

```
var stringP= "hi".rand(1,10)." my".rand(10,100)."name is ".rand(23,54).rand(1,4)
```

Pattern is

```
rand(from,to)
```

Need to get

```
hi5 my54name is 335
```

It possible to use something like that?

```
stringP.replace(/rand(*,*)/g, function(match){
    return match.replace(rand(*,*),Math.floor(Math.random() * (to - from + 1) + from));
});
```

Comment: That is not a valid string in javascript.

Comment: That's not a javascript string concatenation.

Comment: I take example from here http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regular-expressions-in-javascript-part-2/

Comment: That stringp is not valid JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, nearly everything is possible. Yet, you want to use a [one!] proper [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/), and a proper [replace function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
stringP.replace(/rand\((\d+),(\d+)\)/g, function(match, from, to) {
    from = parseInt(from, 10);
    to = parseInt(to, 10);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (to - from + 1) + from);
});
```

Comment: Bergi has got a fast regex quickdraw! Just remember to start with the string properly delimited: `var stringP = "hi rand(1,10) my rand(10,100) name is rand(23,54) rand(1,4)";`

Answer (score 2):

Why are you doing this with regular expressions? Function calls make more sense.

```
function rand (to, from) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (to - from + 1) + from).toString();
}

var stringP= "hi" + rand(1,10) + " my" + rand(10,100) + "name is " + rand(23,54) + rand(1,4);
```

Comment: @Bergi It would be is it leads with two rands. EG `var str = rand(1,100) + rand(1,100);` Without it they would add together instead of concatenate.